# Extremely slow Hadoop CLI

Tags: macos, hadoop

I installed hadoop via brew on my `OS X 10.12.3`. Everything looks great and Hadoop seems to be running. I have an issue though:

Whenever I run an hadoop CLI command, it takes roughly 50 seconds to finish. Is this normal? What is the issue and how can I correct it?

Examples: 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this example command:

```
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console hdfs dfs -ls
```

And you should be able to see what step it gets stuck on (potentially something like group resolution or DNS). If the output is too much, you can redirect it to a file.